# What's going on with NASA's Solar System Dynamics?

Tags: nasa, jpl-horizons, government

JPL's Horizons web interface generates the following orange announcement:

> IMPORTANT: The SSD Announcement email list is now available. Major changes are coming in the near future, including possible hostname and/or URL changes. To be notified of such changes, subscribe to this email list.
>
> Please visit [this page](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi?email_list) for more details.

But if I click that list nothing happens.

1. What are the "Major changes (that) are coming in the near future, including possible hostname and/or URL changes"? Will there be a problem accessing Horizons as usual?
2. Is this US government shut-down related, or a real change/upgrade?

[image]

Comment: Did you click the "visit this page for more details" link?

Answer (score 2):

Today I just received a first announcement from JPL's Jon Giorgini. It announces the first of the "Major changes... coming in the near future, **including possible hostname and/or URL changes**." At least the first of which I'm aware.

The message begins:

> The JPL Solar System Dynamics group's "ssd.jpl.nasa.gov" server, including
>   the Horizons ephemeris system, was moved **to a new machine with a new IP address**
>   on 2019-Oct-22 at about 16:09 UTC (09:09 PDT).

Answer (score 1):

SSB is run by JPL, which although they do a lot of NASA work, and are a NASA operations center, is actually run by the California Institute of Technology (Caltech), and thus are not actually government employees. At the very least, I can tell you that they have actually responded to an email I sent them earlier this week. Of course, they will not be getting the short term funding that they need, at least for any non-military contracts they do. Eventually they will have problems.

As to what is going to happen, not really sure. Maybe they will go to a better web based API? Who knows.

Lastly, the proper URL is actually https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?email_list . I'm not sure why it sometimes points to the wrong one, but... I had the same problem.

Comment: The shutdown would not be noticeably affecting JPL yet (three weeks into the shutdown as I write this), but eventually it will. Nearly all of JPL's funding comes from the government. They can coast for a while on already authorized funds, but not forever.

Comment: @MarkAdler Good point, will edit accordingly.

Comment: @MarkAdler I've received links to https://list.jpl.nasa.gov/ but all I get is `list.jpl.nasa.gov’s server IP address could not be found.` Do you know anything about this? Is it just not set up yet? This *Major changes are coming in the near future, including possible hostname and/or URL changes.* sounds so ominous...

Comment: I don't know, but I would guess that it's a temporary thing. Maybe maintenance. I just successfully subscribed to ssd-announce yesterday.

Comment: @MarkAdler okay thanks, I'll keep an eye on it. All good things come to those who wait, but that's not news to anyone who works on deep space missions ;-)

Comment: @MarkAdler and [here it is](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39538/12102)!